# Obj C Equivalent to Double.doubleToLongBits

Tags: java, objective-c, bytecode-manipulation

I am porting some Java code to Objective C and know enough bitwise to get a headache.  Can someone point me to the objC equivalents to Double.doubleToLongBits and Float.floatToIntBits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no safe way to assign the bits of a `double` to a `long` in Objective C.
In Java, `long` and `double` are both 64bits. In some cases for Objective C, `long` is 32bit and `double` is 64bit.

You should use `long long` instead.

```
int intValue = *((int*)(&floatValue));
long long llValue = *((long long*)(&doubleValue));
```

Answer (score 5):

As **jojoba** noted, `long` isn't guaranteed to be 64 bits wide (though he's wrong to say that it's 32 bits -- `long` is 64 bits wide in Objective-C on 64-bit platforms).  That said, I would use an actual fixed width type instead of `long long`.

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t doubleToBits(double x) {
    const union { double f; uint64_t i; } xUnion = { .f = x };
    return xUnion.i;
}

uint32_t floatToBits(float x) {
    const union { float f; uint32_t i; } xUnion = { .f = x };
    return xUnion.i;
}
```